# Is there a stronger stress on management than on technical education in recent years?

Tags: education, management, software

In my working environment, over the past few years I have observed an increasing stress on developer management and self-management over technical education.

For example, at work I hear lots of discussions about software development processes, about ways to handle software specifications, e.g. through automatic tests, and so on. I hear less discussions about programming concepts / techniques like data structures, lazy evaluation, memoization, and so on.

To give another example, if I asked a colleague how he would manage the complexity of a certain problem, I would expect that he'd indicate me some solution approach (try to solve a subproblem first, identify subtasks) instead of suggesting a programming abstraction (try using pattern X).

Is it just something specific to my working environment or there is a general trend towards management / work organization and away from the more conceptual aspects of programming?

To make my question specific (and answerable), are there any authors or modern schools of thought that consider organizational aspects more important than educational ones for improving developer productivity?

Comment: Are you referring to [Conway's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law) ? Software architecture (modules) being shaped after the team structures, and therefore being constrained by it.

Comment: @rwong: Another very interesting reading. Thanks! No, I was not referring to it. I am referring that I happen to discuss more often about the how to organize my work (e.g. upfront design versus incremental design, or using design diagrams versus not using them, use TDD versus writing tests in a less systematic way) than about which programming techniques to use (e.g. use a memoizer, use a lazy list, avoid mutability, etc).

Comment: I think it's just a natural consequence that a defect-free program is not correlated to the successful outcome of a software project. Low-defect, high-performance software is desirable, but there are other factors that can turn a project into failure.

Comment: Joel Spolsky wrote already something simlilar in 2005: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html - but his reasoning is not in the sense of "modern schools focus more on organizational aspects", but "modern schools neglect lots of important technical aspects in programming education".

Comment: @Doc Brown: The argumentation in Spolsky's article does not look too far from my observation: Instead of training developers to improve their thinking, companies train them to organize their work better. Of course, I find both aspects very important, I just find it curious that one is privileged. Maybe it was discovered that it is more efficient to improve management than to improve education. I would like to know if there are studies about this, or a school of thought that promotes this.

Answer (score 4):

If by "recent years" you mean the last 22 then yes, because that's all the experience I have to go by. Focus on managerial/process oriented aspects of software projects has been really high ever since I started in the field. If you mean just the last 4 or 5 then absolutely not.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is effect of two things:

- Many programmers are not part of the "community". They don't read blogs, they don't frequent SO, they don't watch talks, etc.. That means they have no exposition to the new techniques and paradigms above what they learned in school. And they don't want to.
- On the other hand, managers at least want to learn new things. They want to learn new processes and methodologies. It is just that they prefer learning the management part instead of technical part.

Case in point: Scrum. Scrum is majorly a management methodology. It doesn't talk about TDD, pair programming, refactoring, etc.. It is mostly managers who take the "Scrum Master" certifications. Compare that to the Extreme Programming, which was made by developers for developers and contains both management and technical aspects. It can be said that Scrum is just management subset of Extreme Programming.

And in the end, it is still managers who have the last world. Not developers. So when it comes to solving problems, it is management solution that is chosen. And this simply makes developers believe that those kind of solutions are the right ones.

Answer (score 3):

It is part of a general awakening (or maturing) of software engineering.

You can read about this maturing process in [No Silver Bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet). Although written several decades ago, its observations still hold true today. At different times in history, various programming paradigms, techniques, methodologies, or management styles were hailed as the "silver bullet" in the sense that it can solve all problems.

A more commercial spin on this "no silver bullet" is known as the [Hype Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hype_cycle). This is a thesis brought forward by the advisory firm Gartner for explaining the development, maturity and adoption status of some technologies or methodologies, i.e. various things which had been hailed as the silver bullets in the past.

Two examples of where silver bullets don't work:

**(1)**

A programming paradigm is widely touted as being able to solve a particular type of software requirements, because theoretically source code that is written with this paradigm had certain properties, and these properties will make meeting the said type of software requirements very easy.

It won't work if in reality, no software that makes use of this paradigm to solve that type of software requirements exist. What the theory predicts should have existed, may not exist in the real world, unless one or more companies succeeded in making it happen.

**(2)**

A software architecture is widely touted as having certain desirable characteristics for a certain industry.

A company tries to use this software architecture for this industry, but faces a problem: this company has a large existing code base, and this existing code base doesn't seem to be compatible or portable to this new software architecture.

A silver bullet that seems to work industry-wide may not be suitable for some particular companies due to individual circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting references, but I do not understand how they relate to my question. Do you mean that we are in phase 2 for some new software engineering ideas, and therefore other aspects of programming are temporarily considered less important?

Comment: @Giorgio Regarding your question of "organizational aspect vs. technical aspect", I think this is just the dichotomy between "computer science" and "software engineering"?

Comment: So your thesis is that "software engineering (organizational) aspects are considered more important for software development than "computer science" (technical) ones?

Comment: @Giorgio: no, I don't have a thesis or standpoint by myself. In fact I was trying to guess your thesis in order to answer your question (which seems like I didn't quite get it.) There had been a lot of classical books on the issue of organizational aspects in software engineering, so I'm afraid that (1) the question might be too broad, and (2) it may be primarily opinion-based, both of which makes the question likely to be closed. (Or else, it would make a proper answer look like a long essay.)

Comment: Suppose I have problem X and ask for advice. A methodology answer would be: try to implement a solution using TDD or BDD. A conceptual answer would be: look at streams / lazy lists, you will probably find a suitable solution. Approach 1 suggests a solution method, approach 2 suggests an abstraction that can solve the problem. My feeling is that in the recent years developers tend to look more for better solution methods than for better programming abstractions / concepts.

Answer (score -4):

Try to think in layers, like, let's say TCP/IP: if you're on the physical layer you need to learn the 'language' of the upper layers :))

A programmer shouldn't NEED to learn Management more than a MANAGER should learn Programming: in other words, as long as you have an idea about what's over the fence you're fine...

The next thing is about methods/standards/frameworks, which are GENERAL guidances: they should be adopted and ADAPTED as suitable to any PARTICULAR situation.
Finally, Software Development being a Human activity is prone to FASHION as any other activity: the nowadays trend is AGILE/Scrum/Kanban! [Instead of 'cascade' management, simply because it looks cheaper in many cases (not always) ...and as any other method it works if applied properly by the right people... Otherwise, please take it from someone who has seen it failing, it can exhaust resources faster than light.]

To resume the above, the answer to your question is another question:
would your (any) CEO (if not of a programming background) learn quicker about programming or about management and fashion?

My personal approach to the above: **continuous learning**...

Comment: Please use the preview when posting an answer to make sure it is formatted correctly.  If you are unsure of how to format using Stack Exchange flavor markdown, please read [editing help](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/editing-help).